# I'm trying to search for IP cameras using the ONVIF protocol

Tags: c#, camera, ip, onvif

I am sending ONVIF messages to all IPs via multicast and using CloseTime to receive data for a certain period of time, storing it in a list. However, sometimes I can successfully search for cameras, but other times I cannot. The onvif Device Manager program can search successfully though. What could be the issue with my code? Below is my code."

Here is your translated text:

"I am using the ONVIF Device Manager program to search for IP cameras, but sometimes I am able to successfully search and other times I am not. I am sending ONVIF messages to all IPs via multicast and using CloseTime to receive data for a specific period of time. I store the received data in a list. What could be the problem with my code? Below is my code

```
private static async Task<List<string>> GetSoapResponsesFromCamerasAsync1(int CloseTime)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient())
    {
        System.Net.IPAddress multicastAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250");
        IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 0);
        IPEndPoint multicastEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(multicastAddress, 3702);
        client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        client.Client.Bind(localEndpoint);
        client.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastAddress);

        try
        {
            var soapMessage = Main.util.GetBytes(CreateSoapFindCamera());
            var timeout = System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(CloseTime);
            await client.SendAsync(soapMessage, soapMessage.Length, multicastEndpoint);
            while (timeout > System.DateTime.Now)
            {
                if (client.Available > 0)
                {
                    var receiveResult = await client.ReceiveAsync();
                    var text = Main.util.GetText(receiveResult.Buffer);
                    result.Add(text);
                }
                else { await Task.Delay(100); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception) { Console.WriteLine(exception.Message); }
        finally { client.DropMulticastGroup(multicastAddress); }
     }
     return result;
}

private static string CreateSoapFindCamera()
{
    string messageId = "urn:uuid:" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    const string soap = @"
    <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
    <e:Envelope 
    xmlns:e=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope""
    xmlns:w=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"" 
    xmlns:d=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"" 
    xmlns:dn=""http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl"">
        <e:Header>
        <w:MessageID>{0}</w:MessageID>
        <w:To e:mustUnderstand=""true"">urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</w:To>
   <w:Actiona:mustUnderstand=""true"">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</w:Action>
        </e:Header>
        <e:Body>
        <d:Probe>
          <d:Types>dn:NetworkVideoTransmitter</d:Types>
        </d:Probe>
      </e:Body>
    </e:Envelope>";
        var result = string.Format(soap, messageId);
        return result;
}
```

I used the ONVIF protocol to send SOAP messages and used a while loop to wait for messages for a certain period of time. However, assuming there are 30 cameras, it was rare for all 30 cameras to be successfully searched.

Comment: What you need to keep in mind with anything that is based on UDP: UDP is an inherently **unreliable** protocol. So you may actually need to send several requests to get answers from all devices. Losing packages _must_ be anticipated by the application.

Comment: How should I modify the code to perform a more reliable search?

Comment: I'd probably have a client that is a class member, not local to that function. Then I'd probably use that to just keep on listening, updating a class-level list of devices. Then, if you want to kick-off discovery explicitly, I'd send not one but a "scattershot" of requests. Like one immediatlz, then one some X ms later, then 2*X ms later, then 8*X ms later ... maybe play around until you find a good middleground to not flood the network too much while getting answers from all expected devices most of the time.

Comment: Can you please provide more details for your request? Are you asking for a detailed explanation of the term "scattershot"?

Comment: I meant a burst, not one singular request. But several of them distributed over a certain period of time.

Comment: 'await client.SendAsync(soapMessage, soapMessage.Length, multicastEndpoint);
while
    retries++;
    if (retries >= 4)
        break; // Break the loop if no responses are received after multiple retries
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    delay *= 2; // Exponentially increase the delay for subsequent retries
'

modified my code
Do I need to send multiple times?

Comment: IP: 239.255.255.250 Port: 3702

send a message
sendAsync Receive for a certain period of time after sending message No. 1
In the modified version, Send was processed for a certain period of time, but the same result was obtained.